# Smarty template with comma and decimal

Tags: smarty

I have to calculate a smarty variable with 23,50 Euro e.g if variable = 100 than {$variable+23,50} it should be 123,50 Euro. In template the variable accepts only {$variable+23.50} which gives me 24,50. the same with 1000 Euro {$variable+23,50} I need a value 1.023,50

can someone help me please.

thanks in advance

I have tried replace, string_format etc. but nothing worked.

Comment: Post your code ...(only the relevant part of it)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the {math} from Smarty, like this :

```
{math equation="x + y" x=$variable y=23.50 format="%.2f"}
```

If you want to replace comma by a point, use math replace :

```
{math|replace:",":"."}
```